# Re-trigger CSS Animation with data change in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, animation

I've got a couple of CSS animations using keyframes in Angular - when the page first loads they run fine. However when the data changes and the next question loads on the same component I want to re-trigger the animation. Is there a way to do this?

```
<!--Animations-->
<img [src]="'../../assets/_backgrounds/' + question?.backgroundId + '/l-fnt-1.png'" class="left-front-animation" >
<img [src]="'../../assets/_backgrounds/' + question?.backgroundId + '/r-fnt-1.png'" class="right-front-animation" >
```

CSS Animations:

```
.left-front-animation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -400px;
    -webkit-animation: left 1.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation: left 1.5s forwards;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.right-front-animation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -520px;
    -webkit-animation: right 1s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation: right 1s forwards;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes left {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes left {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes right {
    100% { right: 0; }
}

@keyframes right {
    100% { right: 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-trigger CSS Animation with Angular

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}

let myElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(".left-front-animation"); 

myElement.classList.remove('.left-front-animation').add('.left-front-animation')
```

Comment: Doesn't work in TypeScript - el has no style or offsetHeight properties

Comment: Compiles this time - but still doesn't re-trigger the animation